# Newly added CNContact doesn't have unique identifier when fetched from native

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, cncontact

When i try to add cncontact using saveRequest the identifier which I get from CNMutableContact is different from fetched contacts.

> To fetch all contacts

```
for container in allContainers {
let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: (container.identifier))

do {
    let containerResults = try self.contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: self.keysToFetch as [CNKeyDescriptor])
    results.append(contentsOf: containerResults)
} catch {
    print("Error fetching results for container")
}
```

> Add contact to native

```
request.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
try self.contactStore.execute(request)
```

I referred this link [What is the ":ABPerson" string in CNContact identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379885/what-is-the-abperson-string-in-cncontact-identifier) but no luck

**Note: Account syncing is enabled**

Any suggestions for getting similar contact identifier?